# Sending Database content in Email in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, email, html-email

I want to send email newsletters to members with `images` and content from `Database`. What i achieved is sending text and images to email but the Problem is with the content from `Database`

**How to send Database content(Like user posts) in newsletters?**

**2nd**: I saw many tutorials of sending mail from `ASP.Net`. All of them uses html tags and Mail content in c# with inline css. **Is this the right way**? or can i send whole loaded page in Email

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to send HTML emails that rely heavily on database connectivity it might be easier to use an email service. [JangoMail](https://www.jangomail.com/database-connectivity.aspx) in particular offers real time database  connectivity to MS SQL, MS Access, etc. The interface UI wasn't great the last time I used it, but in terms of database connectivity it's quite powerful.